# How to calculate a pixels world space position on an image plane formed by a virtual camera?

Tags: position, pixel, raytracing

First, this [Calculating camera ray direction to 3d world pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094042/calculating-camera-ray-direction-to-3d-world-pixel) helped me a bit in understanding what the virtual camera setup is like. I don't understand how the vectors work in this setup, and I thought normalized device coordinates had to be used which led me to this page http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-lessons/lesson-6-rays-cameras-and-images/building-primary-rays-and-rendering-an-image/. What I am trying to do is build a ray tracer, and as the question states, find out the pixels position in order to shoot out a ray. What I really, really really would like, is an actually  example showing a virtual camera setup, screen resolution and how to calculate a pixels position, then transform to world space coordinates. Experts!, Thank you for your help! :D

Answer (score 0):

Multiply a matrix by the coordinates. What matrix? There are lots of choices. For example XNA uses a projection matrix, view matrix and world matrix. Applying all of them transforms pixel coordinates into world coordinates or vice versa. Breaking it down this way helps to understand the different transformations going on so you can more easily construct the matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this webpage providing you already with 4 pages of explanation on how these rays are built? It seems like you haven't made the effort to read the content of the link you are referring to. I would suggest you read it first, try to understand it, maybe look at the source code they provide and come back with a real question regarding what you potentially don't understand.
It's all there, and I am not going to re-write what these people seem to have put a lot of energy already to explain! (nor should anybody else really ...).